# Custom folder with subitems in Start menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, pin

Is it possible to pin a folder containing sub items in the Start menu in Windows 7?

I want my custom files to be visible to users via the Start Menu, much like recent files are shown as a sub menu from programs, etc., like Notepad. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not ideal, but it may be workable for you.

I have not been able to or find how to pin a new folder to the start menu (can be done with the taskbar).

I did get a folder to display with recent items (with sub-folders displayed).

What I did was to......

Change the *Downloads* folder name to 'what I want' from your Personal Folder or its Properties.

[image: Custom property image]

Then click on the Start Button, open properties -> click on start menu -> click on customize and then scroll down to Downloads click on Display as a menu.

[image: Image of menu with changed name]

The name change appears in the menu right hand side with folders displayed when you click on jump list. You may wish to change where you download to. I hope this is workable for your needs.

Comment: Nice hack! @mic84

Comment: This looks very promising actually! I can rename the folder and possibly even use my own icon? That would be great! But also, is this stored in the registry or something? Would it be possible to distribute this over a network?

Comment: @Kenny Bones-not sure of reg. - but, click Download Properties- see Location and Customize - maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Open the start menu, right click on *All Programs* and select "open all users".

This will open the folder containing all the folders and links on the start menu. Open the "programs" folder and add folders and links as you like, delete the ones you don't want, and be careful what you delete.

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty good. But I'm still not able to pin this item on the top of the Start menu? I don't ever use the "All Programs" on the Start menu at all anymore. Just use search or the pinned items.