# In House Applications Folder (pin to start)

Tags: windows-7, desktop

If you go to Windows 7 Start -> All Programs -> My Programs Folder it expands the list of programs in the Folder where you can launch any of the programs.

I have a folder with my Company Name where I deploy a bunch of Custom Inhouse Application, about 20 programs.

I would like to see if I could PIN this folder to the Start Menu so that when I clicked on it, it would expand to show all my programs.

I know I could pin each program to the Start Menu, but I don't have enough real estate to show every application that I have built and is in my Program folder.

It is similar to "Microsoft Office", where there are a bunch of programs under that folder.  I want to Pin the Folder that contains the Programs and have it expand like it does when you select it from the All Programs folder.

Sort of Move it UP ONE Level instead of having to go into All Programs.

Comment: I found JumpFolder, which looks like it would work great, but it does not work with my ClickOnce shortcuts...

Answer (score 0):

A couple solutions here: 
https://www.technorms.com/23699/pin-a-folder-to-the-start-menu-windows-7

But here's a simple one

> You can also drag a folder to the Start button, hold for a moment, and
>   the whole menu will open. Then drag upwards to the top of the menu and
>   drop it.

Btw, this is the top google link for "pin a folder to start menu"....

Comment: That adds the Folder to the Start Menu and when clicked it opens Windows Explorer to that Location.  I want the Shortcuts to be displayed.

Comment: Gotcha, have you seen/tried this hack? https://superuser.com/questions/321313/custom-folder-with-subitems-in-start-menu-in-windows-7?rq=1